# Website fails to load, but on refresh loads?

Tags: html, iis, redirect

So my domain is pointed at a redirect file which in turn loads the first page in a website.

It has worked in the past. The host recently switched servers though and said it would be seamless. Now when you navigate to [www.AiySlumlords.com](http://www.AiySlumlords.com) it hits the redirect then fails to load the second page. HOWEVER, if you hit refresh after it fails then it loads?

I have no clue why this isn't working. Here is the redirect file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A web page that points a browser to a different page after 2 seconds</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=./Home/f1.html">
<meta name="keywords" content="automatic redirection">
</head>
<body>
<p>If your browser doesn't automatically go there within a few seconds, you may want to go to <a href="./Home/f1.html">the destination</a> manually.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your server is powered by IIS and ASP.NET, it's better to use ASP.NET to redirect your client, e.g. create an index.aspx page with the following content:

```
<%
  Response.Redirect("~/Home/f1.html", false);
  Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;
  Response.End();
%>
```